# Is it possible to using a serial port in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to use a serial port from vbscript? I can get a Win32_SerialPort object from WMI Services, but all the properties are read only. It will tell me all about a particular serial port but it won't let me actually configure the port and send or receive data.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes it is possible.](http://www.activexperts.com/serial-port-component/howto/vbscript/) But it depends on what you are trying to send/receive and the type of data.

Comment: I want to send a string.(i.e., "Hello World" & vbCRLF)

Comment: Then read the link i posted in my answer. Thatll get you started.

Comment: I did not see the link your answer. While I appreciate the help, using a third party component doesn't help when I give my script to another user. If I can't use the serial drivers/components that come with Windows I will just write my own VB program to do the job. I was hoping writing a script would be faster, plus help me polish my vbscript skills.But it looks like I was mistaken.

Comment: You may have to transfer over supporting DLL's regardless. But anyway, I apologize my answer did not assist you and i wish the best for your future endeavors.